# "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean" on assert

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assert

Code is as followed:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class ContactPageElements {
    public static WebElement element = null;
    public static String baseURL1 = "http://something.com";

    //Clicking logo should take you back to the baseURL
    public static void clickLogo (WebDriver driver) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blah'"));
        element.click();
        String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        assert.assertEquals(currentURL, baseURL1);
    }
}
```

For the assert, i am getting an error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean"

Comment: I think you didn&#39;t close the `ContactPageElements` correctly. There are two `}` at the end of your code. Edit : I'm tired and thought the second one was a class, not a method.

Comment: May just be the formatting. One is for the class, and one is for the method :)

Comment: Yeah I misread that completely. My bad.

Comment: Completely understand that. No worries!

Comment: `currentURL` is probably null.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the assert line and see which parameter is null then trace it back to the why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you have a static import for `assertEquals()` the last line of  `clickLogo()` should simply be:

```
assertEquals(currentURL, baseURL1);
```

Comment: It should, because `assert` is a keyword not just a random class or variable name. Thus using `.` on `assert` is pointless/wrong/nonsense.

Comment: Literally that. Easy enough. Thanks!

Comment: @domoniq-doby Happy to help. Feel free to mark this answer as correct :)